# Queuing scripts in Auto Hot Key

Tags: autohotkey

I have written a AHK script for which the execution time is about 2 hours. I have to execute the same script for multiple projects, one after another.

**Is there a way to queue the scripts in AHK**, so that next project execution can start only after the previous instance of the script is completed??

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the next script from the previous script with `Run`.

Having a "master" script which calls all the other scripts with `RunWait` won't work, because `RunWait` will return before the scripts are completed.

Comment: My scenario involves, 
1. Few scripts that will run repeatedly at certain time intervals for data refresh 
2. Few scripts that will run at the start of every project (Will be triggered by a certain event) 

If a project start script gets triggered, but a data refresh script is running then, i want it to wait till the data refresh script completes execution and then start executing.

Comment: That is a bit more complicated to solve... You'll probably need to communicate between scripts using [`PostMessage`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm)/[`OnMessage`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152742/9253414).